# How to get Crystal Reports parameter from main report to all subreports?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I wonder if there is an easy way to add a parameter from main report to all the subreports? Or alternatively refer to main report's parameter in formula fields in subreports?

I can choose every single one of subreports manually and add a parameter with same name and then do "change subreport links" but there might be something like 30 subreports in each report and to create a parameter with same name to all of them and link takes some time.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to manually link each sub-report to the 'main' report.  You don't need to explicitly create a parameter field in each sub-report--CR will do that for you when you choose a field.

Comment: what if the main report contains subreports? How to link when there's no fields on main report?